# Translate "Excel"-like table into shiny / DT code?

Tags: r, shiny, data-visualization, dt

**Problem:** Is it possible to create such "Excel"-kind table with `DT` or some other package to siplay it in a shiny application? (Remark: this is just a template, actual data needs to be filled)
[image]

Comment: `DT::datatable()` has an `editable` argument. Maybe have a look at `rhandsontable` too.

Comment: See section 2.6 [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) (custom container).